# Как я могу использовать блок omnibox (Как добраться) от google maps на моем сайте?

Tags: google-maps, карты

Суть в следующем. Можно ли использовать стандартные контролы от гугла, добавляя их карту к себе на сайт. Omnibox - это блок где есть два вводимых поля и гугл строит маршрут, показывая при этом построение на автомобиле, общественном транспорте, велосипеде и пешком. Есть ли возможность использовать такой блок у себя на сайте?

Answer (score 0):

#### Как добавить на сайт карту или маршрут

Чтобы встроить в сайт или блог карту или маршрут, выполните следующие действия:

1. Откройте [Google Карты](https://www.google.com/maps).
2. Найдите нужную карту, панораму в Просмотре улиц или маршрут.
3. Нажмите на значок меню [image: menuitem] в левом верхнем углу экрана.
4. Выберите **Ссылка/код**.
5. В верхней части появившегося окна откройте вкладку Код.
6. Выберите размер карты. Затем скопируйте текст в поле и вставьте его в код своего сайта или блога.

**Примечания**

- Получить код в [упрощенном режиме](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966) нельзя.
- Сведения о пробках и другие данные могут быть недоступны на встроенной карте.

---

#### Как поделиться картой или местом

Чтобы поделиться ссылкой на карту, выполните следующие действия:

1. Откройте [Google Карты](https://www.google.com/maps).
2. Откройте карту или панораму из Просмотра улиц.
3. Нажмите на значок меню [image: menuitem].
4. Выберите **Ссылка/код**. Если этого пункта нет в меню, нажмите **Ссылка на карту**.
5. Чтобы сократить адрес, установите флажок "Короткий URL".
6. Скопируйте ссылку в сообщение электронной почты, запись Google+ и т. п.

**Совет.** Ссылку также можно скопировать из адресной строки браузера (недоступно в Internet Explorer 8 и 9).

---

#### Чем можно и нельзя делиться

**Чем можно делиться:**

- картой с отмеченным на ней местом или адресом;
- картой, на которую нанесен маршрут;
- панорамой из Просмотра улиц.

**Чем нельзя делиться:**

- картой, на которой сохранены места, доступные только вам;
- картой, на которой отмечено расстояние между объектами;
- скриншотом или фотографией карты.

---

Оригинал отсюда: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361)

Comment: Вы видимо не понимаете про что я тут говорю. Я говорю про взаимодействие с API, а не то, как мне маршрут добавить до одного места. У меня есть карта, я хочу иметь возможность на моем сайте юзать все тоже самое, что дает гугл. А именно omnibox controls

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, да. Вот такое хочу добавить http://joxi.ru/Y2L5LDlfnJoE1A